# Mostrar botao se estiver logado / esconder se não estiver

Tags: php, session, echo

Desejo mostrar o botão "painel" se o usuário estiver logado, e se não estiver desejo mostrar o botão login, eé possível?

Segue o meu código...

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    "echo "<a href="logado.php" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Painel</a>" . "<br>";
}else{

    echo "<a href="login.php" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Login/Entrar</a>" . "<br>";
}



?>
```

Comment: Você está com uma aspas duplas a mais no seu código, aqui `"echo`. Remova-a. Você também deve escapar as aspas dentro da string. [Veja aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). No mais, a lógica é essa mesma.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo, uma solução simples seria apenas usando Jquery e CSS, irei deixar um exemplo abaixo para você.

```js
$('#btn-post').click(function(){

if($('#name').val()  == "Jorge" && $('#mail').val() == "123"){
   $('p').text('Login efetuado,Botão painel visível!') 
   $('#btn-painel').show();
}
else{
  $('#btn-painel').hide();
  $('p').text('Login incorreto, botão não disponível!') 
}
})
```

```css
#btn-painel{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Mensagem:</label>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button id="btn-post">Clique para testar!</button>
        <button id="btn-painel">Painel</button>
        <p></p>
    </div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Para testar, digite no campo nome "Jorge" e no E-mail = "123", só para simular um login, caso os dados sejam esse, o botão ficara visível, caso não seja, ficará escondido.